# Where to get deployed service and generated wsdl using websphere

Tags: java, web-services, websphere

I am using WebSphere to publish my service as a web service using `@WebService` annotation in eclipse.

Details of the server :

> Product name: **WebSphere Application Server**
>   Product Version: **17.0.0.2**
>   Product edition: **BASE_ILAN**

While deploying the project on the server, the project started successfully and now I wanted to see the generated WSDL through admin console(as I do in Glassfish).But I am not finding any way to view the admin console or any directory which is having the generated WSDL(I am using mac os)

However, I can see(in eclipse) my service is deployed successfully, see attached image:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it's not available in the admin center however you can retrieve it from the service using a web browser.

Look in messages.log to find the context root of your webservices app, you'll see something like: 
`Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:29080/hello_jaxws/`

Then to find the service you might need to know a bit about the service.  If the name of the service isn't in an @WebService annotation, and the class isn't remapped in web.xml, then it's the name of the class + "Service".  So in my case the name of the class is HelloService, so the url to my service is 
`http://localhost:29080/hello_jaxws/HelloServiceService`

A browser should return 
`Hello! This is a CXF Web Service`  from that url.

Finally, add ?wsdl to it to get the wsdl 
`http://localhost:29080/hello_jaxws/HelloServiceService?wsdl`

Comment: thanks for answering, could you please explain the way to do that.

Comment: sorry, it did not work for me, I tried this earlier also. Like in my case
Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9080/SoapWebServices/

and the service name is ProductCatalog.java so I tried http://localhost:9080/SoapWebServices/ProductCatalogService and http://localhost:9080/SoapWebServices/ProductCatalogService?wsdl but every time got the error 

Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /ProductCatalogService

Comment: Make sure you have the `<feature>jaxws-2.2</feature>` in your server.xml.  Turn on trace like this: `<logging maxFileSize="20" maxFiles="10" traceFileName="trace.log" traceSpecification="*=info:com.ibm.ws.jaxws.*=all"/>` Restart, and look for the line like this: 
`com.ibm.ws.jaxws.metadata.EndpointInfo       > addAddress Entry                                                                                                                /HelloServiceService`

Along with the "web appliction available" message, that gives you the rest of the URL.   The URL is case-sensitive.

Comment: Thank you, JAX-WS was not in the list of features in my WebSphere, I have updated it by "./installUtility install jaxws-2.2" and now I am able to access my service and WSDL through URL. You can add this one in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it also when you navigate to {your service} -> Service providers -> {your service} -> WSDL document (from additional properties).

Look there for "soap:address" element, and copy the "location" value/address to your browser with anding "?wsdl" to the end of it.